# SSH doesn't detect authenticationmethod

Tags: server, ssh, sftp, pam

So basically I'm trying to create an SFTP account for a part of my server that doesn't need an SSH-Key nor googles-2fa-pam module. I've got the following setting in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
Match User sharex
    PubkeyAuthentication no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    AuthenticationMethods password
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /home/sharex
```

This is at the bottom of my /etc/pam.d/sshd file:

```
# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

The error when running "service ssh status":

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-01-19 11:22:25 CET; 52min ago
  Process: 20132 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20143 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4583)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
       └─20143 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Jan 19 11:22:25 mango systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jan 19 11:22:25 mango sshd[20132]: Disabled method "password" in 
AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,password"
Jan 19 11:22:25 mango sshd[20143]: Disabled method "password" in AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,password"
Jan 19 11:22:25 mango sshd[20143]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port XXX.
Jan 19 11:22:25 mango sshd[20143]: Server listening on :: port XXX.
Jan 19 11:22:25 mango systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jan 19 11:22:44 mango sshd[20224]: error: Disabled method "password" in AuthenticationMethods list "publickey,password"
Jan 19 11:22:46 mango sshd[20224]: Failed password for sharex from 127.0.0.1 port 56442 ssh2
Jan 19 11:22:47 mango sshd[20224]: Connection closed by authenticating user sharex 127.0.0.1 port 56442 [preauth]
```

When I try logging into the account via ssh:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Output of ssh -v:

`root@mango ~ # ssh -v sharex@localhost -p XXX
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port XXX.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubunt                                                                                                                                                             u-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:XXX as 'sharex'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit                                                                                                                                                             > compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit                                                                                                                                                             > compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Lj/m0+cUQjvYHaXu57qYTtTeg878                                                                                                                                                             c6KgQxk03AhOcUw
debug1: Host '[localhost]:XXX' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rs                                                                                                                                                             a-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
sharex@localhost's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
Permission denied, please try again.`

Would anyone be able to assist me or try to hint me in the right direction as I don't know what I could do. If you need any more information such as configuration files just reply below :)
Thank you!

Comment: Try logging in with `ssh -v`

Comment: Did you restart/reload the SSH server to apply the configuration change?

Comment: @pa4080 I used service ssh restart to restart the ssh service.

Comment: @waltinator I still can't login using the following command ssh -v sharex@localhost -p XXX

Comment: My suggestion that you use the `-v` option was to make `ssh` display information. Please edit your post and show us the command, and its output.

Comment: @waltinator here is the output: https://hastebin.com/edomicoqak.makefile

Comment: That pastbin link displays a blank page, but when I save it, it just shows an html document. Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1111112/edit ) your post and add the result of the `ssh -v`, formatted with the `{}` tool

Comment: Alright, @waltinator I've added it to the main post (question). Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: It looks like `ssh` and `sshd` can't agree on key exchange, so they drop back to `password`. But it looks like `sharex` doesn't have a password set. Look at `ssh-copy-id` (`man ssh-copy-id`, `less $(type -p ssh-copy-id)`. Are you command-line-literate?

Comment: @waltinator I sadly don't understand the command I'm supposed to enter...

Comment: Does the `~sharex` (or `getent passwd sharex | cut -d: -f7`) have a `.ssh` subdirectory? Is `root@localhost`'s key in `~sharex/.ssh/authorized_keys`? Can `sharex` login?

Comment: @waltinator "ls -al" doesn't return any ".ssh" subdirectory for "~sharex". "getent passwd sharex | cut -d: -f7" only returns "/bin/bash" and "~sharex/.ssh/authorized_keys" is no directory. I would just want to remember you that I want the sftp use to login without any ssh key and no 2fa authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the UsePAM yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config or ssh_config

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```